# Strange comparison of `'quote` and `'lambda` in Scheme (guile)

Tags: switch-statement, scheme, quote, guile

Let see my code

Code1:

```
(eqv? 'lambda 'quote)
```

return `#f`

Code2:

```
(case 'lambda ('quote "equal") (else "not equal"))
```

return `"not equal"` but generate a warning `;;; <stdin>:17:0: warning: duplicate datum quote in clause ((quote quote) "equal") of case expression (case (quote lambda) ((quote quote) "equal") (else "not equal"))`

Code3: **strange result**

```
 (case 'quote ('lambda "equal"))
```

return `"equal"` and without warning

I interpreted code using `guile (GNU Guile) 2.0.11`. And here is the description of `case` syntax from [gnu](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/docs-1.8/guile-ref/if-cond-case.html)

> The the result of this evaluation is compared against all datums using eqv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'<something>` is an *abbreviation* for the *list* `(quote <something>)`.  In Scheme, the case form should be a list (in some Lisps, e.g., Common Lisp, it can also be a single non-list element, representing the list of just that element), so that you can do, e.g.:

```
(case n
  ((0) 'zero)                 ; in Common Lisp, could also be (0 'zero)
  ((1 2 3) 'one-two-or-three)
  ((4 5) 'four-or-five))
```

When you do:

```
(case some-symbol
   ('quote 'it-was-quote))
```

You're doing

```
(case some-symbol
  ((quote quote) 'it-was-quote))
```

So you're providing a list, and it's got a duplicate element.  There's nothing *wrong* with that, but it's usually unexpected, and so you get a warning.

By that reasoning

```
(case 'quote ('lambda "equal"))
```

is the same as

```
(case 'quote ((quote lambda) "equal"))
```

and, since the symbol **quote** is in the list **(quote lambda)**, the case matches, and you get "equal".  The moral of the story is: "don't quote the cases in case."  That is, you should be doing:

```
(case 'quote
  ((lambda) "equal"))
```

Comment: that is awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In Scheme, the "single datum" version is not valid; the clauses must always consist of a list of datums. Also, these datums are always compared using `eqv?`, so strings and non-empty lists will never (reliably) match.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Good catch!  In Common Lisp, the "keys" part is a list designator:  a list of keys, or a single key designating the list of just that key.  I've updated my answer to be Scheme-centric.

Comment: Cool! You should also either remove the `(lambda "equal")` case or mark it CL-only.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Oh, missed that one!  Fixed now.